# List outlook MailBox folder hierarchy using recursion- Vbscript

Tags: recursion, vbscript, outlook

I am having problems on recursing through the outlook mail folders.

```
Function listsubfolders(folParent)
'If folParent.Folders.count = 0 Then
'WScript.Echo folParent.name
'Else
    For Each subfolder In folParent.Folders
        tempstr = folParent.name  & ">" & listsubfolders(subfolder)
        WScript.Echo tempstr
    Next
'End If 

End Function
```

Comment: What problems do you have? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to list all subfolders into folder using recursion.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,ws,RootFolder,LogFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "txt"
If fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then
    fso.DeleteFile(LogFile)
End If
Set RootFolder = fso.GetFolder(Browse4Folder())
Call ListSubFolders(RootFolder)
ws.run DblQuote(LogFile)
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub ListSubFolders(Folder)
    Dim Subfolder
    Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Call WriteLog(Subfolder.Path)
        Call ListSubFolders(Subfolder.Path) 'Call Recursive Sub
    Next
End Sub 
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText)
    Dim fs,ts,LogFile
    Const ForAppending = 8
    LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "txt"
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForAppending,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function Browse4Folder()
    Dim objShell,objFolder,Message
    Message = "Please select a folder in order to scan into it and its subfolders"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0,Message,1,"c:\Programs")
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
    Browse4Folder = objFolder.self.path
end Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: How can the sample code help in that case? Do you know why the source code shown above is not working?

Comment: I just give a general example to do with recursion and for that you downvote my reply ? ? ?

Comment: The post doesn't answer the question. It is useless.